# Nodejs: Downloading file from s3 and then writing to filesystem

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream

I am able to download the file from s3 bucket like so:

```
 const fileStream = s3.getObject(options).createReadStream();
    const writableStream = createWriteStream(
        "./files/master_driver_profile_pic/image.jpeg"
    );
    fileStream.pipe(fileStream).pipe(writableStream);
```

But the image is not getting written properly. Only a little bit of the image is visible and the rest is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should first createWriteStream and then createReadStream. [(Check the docs)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-sdk-for-nodejs-now-generally-available/)

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();  
var params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myImageFile.jpg'};  

var file = require('fs').createWriteStream('/path/to/file.jpg');
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(file);
```

**OR**

you can go without streams:

```
// Download file
let content = await (await s3.getObject(params).promise()).Body;

// Write file
fs.writeFile(downloadPath, content, (err) => {
   if (err) { console.log(err); }
});
```